# How to test Evernote's Android Jobs?

Tags: android, testing, android-job

How do I test Jobs created with [Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library? Any ideas on unit testing, instrumented testing or even manual testing are appreciated, I just want to check if it works as expected.

To be specific, I have a job that performs an HTTP request every N hours:

```
package com.kondenko.yamblzweather.job;


import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.evernote.android.job.Job;
import com.evernote.android.job.JobRequest;
import com.kondenko.yamblzweather.model.entity.WeatherData;
import com.kondenko.yamblzweather.ui.weather.WeatherInteractor;
import com.kondenko.yamblzweather.utils.SettingsManager;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class UpdateWeatherJob extends Job {

private WeatherInteractor interactor;
private String cityId;
private String units;
private long refreshRateHr;

// Do not delete, needed for job creation
public static final String TAG = "UpdateWeaterJob";

@Inject
public UpdateWeatherJob(WeatherInteractor interactor, SettingsManager settingsManager) {
    this.interactor = interactor;
    this.cityId = settingsManager.getSelectedCity();
    this.units = settingsManager.getSelectedUnitValue();
    this.refreshRateHr = settingsManager.getRefreshRate();
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {
    WeatherData data = interactor.getWeather(cityId, units).blockingGet();
    return data != null ? Result.SUCCESS : Result.FAILURE;
}


public void buildJobRequest(String name) {
    new JobRequest.Builder(UpdateWeatherJob.TAG)
            .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(refreshRateHr))
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build()
            .schedule();
}

}
```

Comment: Did you find any more info?

Comment: @DuckN'Bear nope, I ended up with having to put logs in the job and reading them to make sure it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We at Evernote test jobs the following way:

- Unit tests -> We tend to extract the logic into actions, similar to presenters in a MVP setup. This removes Android dependencies and the actions are unit testable.
- QA -> We have QA options to trigger jobs manually. This way our QA team can verify that the job produces the correct output
- Verifying timing -> There we rely on the logs.

You also should take a look at [these slides](https://speakerdeck.com/vrallev/doo-z-z-z-z-z-e?slide=85). ADB can be really helpful to verify curtain assumptions.